# Delay Building Of a Request

Tags: c#, .net, rest, architecture

I'm trying to create a third party library to consume an API.

I've created a bunch of classes which resolve different api calls e.g:

```
public class AccountsEndpoint: IAccountsEndpoint
{
    public async Task<Account> GetAsync(id)
    {
        return await this.BuildUrl(id).GetJsonAsync();
    }
    //etc...
}

public class NotificationsEndpoint: INotificationsEndpoint
{
    public async Task<Notification> SetPrimary(id)
    {
        return await this.BuildUrl(id).AppendSegment("Primary")
                         .PostJsonAsync(null, cancellationToken)
                         .ReceiveJson<Notification>())();
    }
}
```

I have a large number of these endpoints and I would like to run some additional code before each one of these calls,

e.g For example if my oauth token is invalid I would want to get a new access token and retry the request automatically.

I would prefer **NOT** to have to wrap all api calls with a handler like:

```
public async Task<Notification> SetPrimary(id)
{
    return await new CustomErrorHandler(() => 
                     this.BuildUrl(id).AppendSegment("Primary")
                       .PostJsonAsync(null, cancellationToken)
                       .ReceiveJson<Notification>())()).ExecuteAsync();
}
```

If I were to do something like that I would have to remember to use the error handler on all endpoint, when I feel like there's a better way to invert the control.  (Alternatively, I could generate dummy interface and have the wrapping logic there but that arises the same issues as manually adding the calls).

How can I wrap all of the calls with error handler logic?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the presented code as it does not provide enough context for me to have a clear picture of what it is suppose to be doing. That said however, you mentioned pipeline and the middleware pattern came to mind. If you have a pipeline that manages requests then you can insert a middleware early in the pipeline that was satisfy the behavior you seek

Comment: similar to how message handlers are used in Web API

Comment: @nkosi thanks for your response I’ll check that out

Comment: You appear to be using Flurl. these might be of some interest to you. https://flurl.io/docs/configuration/ and https://flurl.io/docs/extensibility/

Comment: @Nkosi hmm I guess I could configure the on error but that still bring up the issue for calling for each method in the interface

Comment: not if you apply it globally.

Comment: @Nkosi yeah but that semi ties me into the flurl client as a dependency, but I guess that’s a good work around thanks!

Comment: You are already coupled to Flurl based on what has been shown so far. I still like the middleware approach :)

Comment: @Nkosi Good point I’ll use the flurl client to configure the errors for now. That over solves the problem, if you want to post that as an answer I’ll accept it as an answer.  Since it’s kind of an x y problem, and that resolved my real problem of having to repeat code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what has been shown so far, the endpoints appear to be using Flurl.

Under the hood that framework uses `HttpClient`, which should provide an extensibility point to take advantage of the request pipeline.

According to [documentation](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/), you should be able to configure a global setting to achieve the desired behavior.

For example

> I have a large number of these endpoints and I would like to run some additional code before each one of these calls
>
> e.g For example if my oauth token is invalid I would want to get a new access token and retry the request automatically.

```
private async Task HandleOAuthAsync(HttpCall call) {
    //...check response and if token expired perform some action or trigger some event
}

//...


//register globally
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => settings.AfterCallAsync = HandleOAuthAsync);
```

There is even the ability to go down to the client level for more direct access to the client or message handlers if so desired.